# getTime() retorna unixtme diferente da data

Tags: javascript, node.js, data

Tenho uma string de data que quando atribuo esta string em um `date` e posteriormente vou pegar o `getTime` dela, se a aplicação estiver rodando em maquinas distintas o unixtime retornado vem com algumas horas diferentes sendo de duas horas a diferença.

O porque e como acertar isto para que o unixtime venha com a data da string que passei.

Código:

```
var data = "2018-02-12T10:20:00"
var dataString = new Date(data);
dataString.getTime();
```

Comment: As duas maquinas estão e fusos horários diferentes ? Se sim construa a data indicando também o fuso horário

Comment: Quero deixar justamente esta parte dinamica. Mas uma dúvida é se eu montei a string com a data que queria porque ele pegaria fuso da maquina no getTime?